# Converting Data in a C# List from one type to another.

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to learn Linq a little better so I apologies in advance if this is a silly question.

**Given the following classes:**

```
class FormData 
{
   public string CustomerId {get; set;}
   public string FieldId {get; set;} 
   public string FieldValue {get; set;}
}

class CustomerDetails 
{
   public string CustomerId {get; set;}
   public FormField[] Fields {get; set;} 
}

class FormField
{
   public string FieldId {get; set;}
   public string FieldValue {get; set;} 
}
```

**I'm trying to convert this data**

```
// example incoming data set 
List<FormData> formData = new List<FormData> {
   new FormData { CustomerId = 1, FieldId = "FirstName", FieldValue = "Peter" },   
   new FormData { CustomerId = 1, FieldId = "LastName", FieldValue = "Smith" },   
   new FormData { CustomerId = 1, FieldId = "PetsName", FieldValue = "Spot" },  
   new FormData { CustomerId = 2, FieldId = "FirstName", FieldValue = "Dougie" },   
   new FormData { CustomerId = 2, FieldId = "LastName", FieldValue = "Fresh" },   
   new FormData { CustomerId = 2, FieldId = "PetsName", FieldValue = "Skittles" }, 
   new FormData { CustomerId = 3, FieldId = "FirstName", FieldValue = "Sam" },   
   new FormData { CustomerId = 3, FieldId = "LastName", FieldValue = "Reynolds" },   
   new FormData { CustomerId = 3, FieldId = "PetsName", FieldValue = "Taco" }              
};
```

**to this**

```
// desired out going data set 
List<CustomerDetails> customerDetails = new List<CustomerDetails> {
   new CustomerDetails {
    CustomerId : 1, 
    Fields : [
           new FormField {FieldId = "FirstName", FieldValue = "Peter"}, 
           new FormField {FieldId = "LastName", FieldValue = "Smith"},
           new FormField {FieldId = "PetsName", FieldValue = "Spot"}
        ]
    },
   new CustomerDetails {
    CustomerId : 2, 
    Fields : [
           new FormField {FieldId = "FirstName", FieldValue = "Dougie"}, 
           new FormField {FieldId = "LastName", FieldValue = "Fresh"},
           new FormField {FieldId = "PetsName", FieldValue = "Skittles"}
        ]
    },
   new CustomerDetails {
    CustomerId : 3, 
    Fields : [
           new FormField {FieldId = "FirstName", FieldValue = "Sam"}, 
           new FormField {FieldId = "LastName", FieldValue = "Reynolds"},
           new FormField {FieldId = "PetsName", FieldValue = "Taco"}
        ]
    }
};
```

Here's how I'm currently doing it... there's gotta be a better way right?

```
var customerIds = formData.Distinct().Select(x => x.CustomerId).ToList();

var results = new List<CustomerDetails>(); 

foreach (var id in customerIds)
{
    var customerDetails = new CustomerDetails();
    customerDetails.CustomerId = id;

    var fields = new List<GuestItemDataFieldResult>(); 

    foreach (var f in formData.Where(x => x.CustomerId == id))
    {
    var field = new FormField();
        field.FirstName = f.FirstName; 
        field.LastName = f.LastName; 
        field.PetsName = f.PetsName;

        fields.Add(field); 
    }

    customerDetails.Fields = fields.ToArray(); 

    results.Add(customerDetails); 
}
```

Comment: What would you consider to be better?  Less code?  Faster processing?

Comment: @mclaassen I believe GroupBy is what I'm looking for but I can't wrap my head around the syntax (pretty new to LINQ still).

Comment: @paqogomez can't install any third party libraries per client specs... weak!

Comment: Talk to someone, modify the specs.  JSON.Net is the way to handle json objects, which is what you're creating.

Comment: Not being able to use 3rd party libs is a silly requirement.

Comment: @paqogomez I agree and I like your style, however big stupid companies can sometimes have big stupid policies.

Comment: @McCheeseIt I feel you on that one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var newData =
    formData.GroupBy(g1 => g1.CustomerId)
        .Select(
            s1 =>
                new CustomerDetails
                {
                    CustomerId = s1.Key.ToString(),
                    Fields =
                        s1.Select(s2 => new FormField {
                                FieldId = s2.FieldId, 
                                FieldValue = s2.FieldValue})
                            .ToArray()
                });
```

Comment: that ``s1 =>`` on it's own line is killing me